# android : Black label for NavigationDrawer with heme.AppCompat.Light theme

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I'm using such styles for the activity with Navigation Drawer :

```
 <style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#03a5e7</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_white_color</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_white_color</item>
</style>
```

My color :

```
 <color name="text_white_color">#FFFFFF</color>
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Nevertheless the title color of the NavigationDrawer is black. What is the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it with setting

```
 <style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#03a5e7</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_white_color</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>
```

The thing is in setting `DarkActionBar`